# how do I read __version__ for modules found with ModuleFinder?

Tags: python, version

I am using `ModuleFinder` to get a list of all of the modules imported in my Python program. Some of my modules have `__version__` numbers in them. How do I read the `__version__` variable?

Here is my test code. It doesn't work:

```
__version__ = "1.1.1"

from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script(__file__)
for name,mod in sorted(finder.modules.items()):
    try:
        ver = mod.__version__
    except AttributeError as e:
        ver = '--'
    print(name, ver, mod.__file__)
```

The output looks like this:

```
$ python3 demo.py|head
__future__ -- /Users/simsong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/__future__.py
__main__ -- demo.py
_ast -- None
_bisect -- /Users/simsong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-36m-darwin.so
_blake2 -- /Users/simsong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-36m-darwin.so
_bootlocale -- /Users/simsong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_bootlocale.py
_bz2 -- /Users/simsong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-darwin.so
_codecs -- None
_collections -- None
_collections_abc -- /Users/simsong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod` is not a regular Python module object; it is an instance of the `modulefinder.Module` class. It does have mapping of global names though, in the form of a dictionary attribute named `globalnames`. You can *verify* that your module has a global name `__version__` by checking that mapping:

```
for name, mod in sorted(finder.modules.items()):
    ver = mod.globalnames.get('__version__', '--')
    print(name, ver, mod.__file__)
```

This'll print `1`; meaning the name exists. That's because the actual module is *not loaded*, only the bytecode is analyzed without executing.

You would either have to actually import the module, or do your own bytecode analysis to get the *value* of global names. The `Module` class has a `__code__` attribute you could scan to see what value was on the stack when `__version__` is being stored:

```
import dis

def load_version_string(codeobj):
    """Returns the constant value loaded for the `__version__` global

    Requires that `__version__` is set from a literal constant value.

    """
    instructions = dis.get_instructions(codeobj)
    for instr in instructions:
        if instr.opname == 'LOAD_CONST':
            nxtop = next(instructions, None)
            if nxtop.opname == 'STORE_NAME' and nxtop.argval == '__version__':
                return instr.argval
```

then use:

```
for name, mod in sorted(finder.modules.items()):
    ver = '--'
    if '__version__' in mod.globalnames:
        ver = load_version_string(mod.__code__)
    print(name, ver, mod.__file__)
```

Now the output for `__main__` changes to show the version number:

```
$ python3 demo.py | grep __main__
__main__ 1.1.1 demo.py
```

Comment: Ah. Hm... Thanks.

Comment: @vy32: I've added a method of loading the `__version__` constant from the code object, if there is one.

Comment: That's very cool, although it does depend on the cpython bytecode. The code I just wrote looks at `sys.modules[name].__version__` if `name` is in `sys.modules`, which seems to work well for my case. But your code is super-cool!

Comment: @vy32: yes, and `sys.modules[name]` only exists because some code actually imported the module (so the top-level module bytecode was executed).

Comment: indeed. I've written a program that prints a "certificate" which includes the name and sha1 of every imported module. So I really do only care about the modules that have been actually imported. I wish that the list of system modules wasn't six pages. "batteries included" indeed....

Comment: @vy32 well, if your script uses certain modules, then there’s a transitive dependency graph attached to that; those modules don’t operate in isolation. If you only want direct imports, then do your own analysis.

Comment: I want the transitive dependency graph. The certificate gets generated at the end of the run, so it should get everything that was imported, unless some module covertly deleted itself.